# Generate and Require Input of a Randomly-Generated Password

Tags: python, windows, random, getpasswd

My program needs to remember a specific pre-determined password which has been assigned to a variable so that the user input must match it.

```
import random

password = [chr(random.randint(33, 126)) for x in range(6)]

print("Your password is: {}".format(" ".join(password)))

import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass(password)

if (pswd == password):
   print("Access granted")
else:
   print("Access denied")
```

In the code they receive their password and then they need to input it. I've removed a massive chunk of irrelevant coding and so the main thing is that the user gets their password and later on they have to input it.
So the password is a set of random characters, which then is the password that the user needs to remember and input when required.

It's not working, and I was wondering if someone could help please.

Also, is there a way to remove the red writing (`GetPassWarning`) that appears on the shell due to the importation of `getpass.getpass()`?

Thanks.

Comment: `password` is a list, not the string of characters that you printed.

Comment: does it need to be a string in order for it to work?

Comment: Yes, because `pswd` is a string. Comparing a string to a list won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here, but you're on the right track!

Try this:

```
import random
import getpass

password = "".join([chr(random.randint(33, 126)) for x in range(6)])

print("Your password is: {}".format(password))

pswd = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")

if (pswd == password):
   print("Access granted")
else:
   print("Access denied")
```

First, you need to use `"".join()"` instead of `" ".join()`, unless you want a space between each character. Second, you need to use `"".join()"` at the point where you define `password`, because it needs to be a string, equivalent to what you want the user to enter, not a `list`.

Thirdly, the argument for [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) is the prompt to ask the user to enter the password, not the password itself. `getpass()` doesn't need to know what the password is; it just helps you hide input-echoing from the user while they enter their password.

> **getpass.getpass([prompt[, stream]])**
>
> Prompt the user for a password without echoing. The user is prompted using the string prompt, which defaults to 'Password: '. On Unix, the prompt is written to the file-like object stream. stream defaults to the controlling terminal (`/dev/tty`) or if that is unavailable to `sys.stderr` (this argument is ignored on Windows).

**Edit**

The red error you're seeing is because of this (from the `getpass()` manual page linked above):

> If echo free input is unavailable `getpass()` falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from `sys.stdin` and issuing a `GetPassWarning`.

This is likely a Windows-only problem, and under a Linux / POSIX environment, input would be hidden.

To fix this error under Windows, `getpass()` tries to use the [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) module. I don't have a Windows machine to test with, but try running `import msvcrt` at a Python prompt or in a script and see if it works or fails, and post any errors you see in the comments. It looks like you'd get this error under Windows only if `msvcrt` fails to import, or if `sys.stdin` isn't functioning as expected.

Also, as [@Jasper Bryant-Greene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174521/jasper-bryant-greene) awesomely-suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34569957/145279), we can use a warnings filter to hide the warning, if the underlying issue with `msvcrt` cannot be fixed:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    pswd = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
```

Comment: This works thanks! But the same problem arises with this red writing appearing on the shell.

Comment: Your password is: gG)Xs]

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\getpass.py", line 92
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Enter password: gG)Xs]
Access granted

Comment: The above is what appears with the red bit from Warning onwards

Comment: I just added a note about this error. It happens when `getpass()` fails to change terminal-echo, which seems to be a Windows-specific problem you're experiencing.

Comment: No problem at all. Added some more info as well. If anyone wants to read what I looked at to figure out the Windows issues, see the [`getpass() ` source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/getpass.py) here :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `password` to the string that you get after joining, so you can compare it to the string that the user enters.

```
import random

password = " ".join([chr(random.randint(33, 126)) for x in range(6)])

print("Your password is: {}".format(password)

import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")

if (pswd == password):
   print("Access granted")
else:
   print("Access denied")
```

Comment: I'm just confused by the output on the shell. It prints the password as required but then as part of the whole getpass thing it prints the password again but I want the user to input the password

Comment: It's printing the result of `.join()`. But that's not what's in `password`.

Comment: The argument to `getpass` is the prompt. So it was printing the saved password.

Comment: If you have some free time please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594250/multiple-columns-vs-one-big-capacity-column).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
password = [chr(random.randint(33, 126)) for x in range(6)]
print("Your password is: {}".format(" ".join(password))
```

… use:

```
password = "".join(chr(random.randint(33, 126)) for x in range(6))
print("Your password is: {}".format(password))
```

so that `password` is a `str` rather than a `list`.

To prevent printing the password again as part of the password prompt, and suppress the `GetPassWarning` (suppression only necessary if you can’t fix the problem, which as mentioned in another post could be related to the [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) module), you can change:

```
pswd = getpass.getpass(password)
```

… to:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    pswd = getpass.getpass("Enter password:")
```

(By passing `password` as the first argument to `getpass.getpass`, you’re currently telling it to use the password itself as the password prompt.)

Comment: This is the output for example:     Your password is: ` r W [ 3 N

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\getpass.py", line 92
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
` r W [ 3 N
Access denied

Comment: Upvote for mentioning `catch_warnings()`; I added a note about it at the end of my post with proper credit to you! :) Thanks.