# Multiple columns VS one big-capacity-column?

Tags: mysql, performance, data-structures

I have a table like this:

```
// table_A
+--------+---------------+------------+
|   id   |  short-text   | long-text  |
+--------+---------------+------------+
 int(11)    varchar(200)      text         // <= type
```

**Note1:** Always one of `sort-text` or `long-text` is `NULL`. Never both of them aren't containing data. Like this:

```
+--------+---------------+------------+
|   id   |  short-text   | long-text  |
+--------+---------------+------------+
| 1      |some character |  NULL      |
| 2      |some character |  NULL      |
| 3      |some character |  NULL      |
| 4      |some character |  NULL      |
| 5      |some character |  NULL      |
| 6      |NULL           |  some text |
| 7      |some character |  NULL      |
| 8      |some character |  NULL      |
| 9      |some character |  NULL      |
| 10     |some character |  NULL      |
| 11     |some character |  NULL      |
| 12     |NULL           |  some text |
+--------+---------------+------------+
```

**Note2:** As you see in the above table example, always there is 5 rows which `long-text` is `NULL` and then 1 row which `short-text` is `NULL`.

---

Now my question is, that above structure is better or creating just one column (`type = text`) instead of both those columns? something like this:

```
// table_B
+--------+---------------------+
|   id   | short-and-long-text |
+--------+---------------------+
 int(11)         text                // <= type
```

And here is table containing data:

```
+--------+---------------------+
|   id   | short-and-long-text |
+--------+---------------------+
| 1      | some character      |
| 2      | some character      |
| 3      | some character      |
| 4      | some character      |
| 5      | some character      |
| 6      | some text           |
| 7      | some character      |
| 8      | some character      |
| 9      | some character      |
| 10     | some character      |
| 11     | some character      |
| 12     | some text           |
+--------+---------------------+
```

---

Well, which one is more efficient and optimize? `table_A` or `table_B` ?

**Note3:** I always looking up by ID.

Comment: I suspect it will depend on the storage engine you're using. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html Do you run into problems using the more convenient structure, or is this question hypothetical?

Comment: @a1337q hypothetical.

Comment: then I guess you have to be more specific about the question. Efficient for what? Maybe you can also consider posting your question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @a1337q Ah ok,I will ask there. tnx

Comment: Is this "more efficient" for reading or for writing.

Comment: @TomPage Good question ...! Actually I need to both of them ..! In total, Which is Better?

Comment: Obviously you need to do both of them but the most efficient approach for one is probable not the most efficient for another.

In terms of space used the single column will probably take up a few less bytes in storage as you still need to store the fact that a column is null somehow. So I'd say that.

Comment: `TEXT` columns are less efficient to access, because they're stored in separate files instead of in the database file itself. And they can't be indexed fully like `VARCHAR` columns can, you can only index a prefix of the column. The performance difference between 1 and 2 columns in general is probably negligible.

Comment: In summary, the difference will depend heavily on the types of queries you use against the table.

Comment: @Barmar - `TEXT` and "large" `VARCHAR` columns _may_ be stored separately from the record.  It depends on the Engine and the `row_format` _and_ the size.

Comment: @Shafizadeh - Which way would your code be simpler?  Go with that.

Comment: @RickJames Got it ..! thanks.