# SQL - join on free text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, join, contains

I have two tables from two different databases that I want to join together but I don't have a column on which this can be easily done by a join.

In table A I have a table with server names

In table B I have a table where one of the columns has a free text field (description).

I want to be able to create a search that searches for the server name within the description column and then add that description column onto the end of table A.

For example:

```
Table A              Table B
name                 date
server               description
customer             

Output
name
server
customer
description (join on searching for server name in description)
```

Comment: As posted this doesn't make a lot of sense to me. I think you are trying to do a wildcard search but not really sure.

Comment: What do you want to happen if multiple rows in table B contain the server name from table A? Is it possible that you might end up with Server1 and Server12 (or something similar) such that finding one name in the description could cause a false positive of finding the other?

Comment: What code did you try?   Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a full text index on description, then you can use `like`:

```
SELECT A.name, A.server, A.customer, B.description
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON ' ' + B.description + ' ' LIKE '% ' + A.server ' %';
```

Comment: Great ...! +1 *(btw if you have some free time please take a look at [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594250/multiple-columns-vs-one-big-capacity-column))*